# Script in bash to do something when a file is modified

Tags: bash, inotify, inotifywait

I'm trying to make a script to do something when a file is modified. This would work if I run the watcher in another terminal and I edit the file in another vim instance.

However, what I want is that the script opens the vim instance and then run the watcher to do things when I save the file.

This is my script, `run.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
vim chart.csv

inotifywait --quiet --recursive --monitor --event modify chart.csv | while read; do
    notify-send "hi, world"
done
```

Comment: That script isn't going to detect a change, because the `inotifywait` won't run until the `vim` exits.  You can add a `&` to the `vim` command to have it run in the background. If you're looking for one file, you don't want `--recursive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gnome-terminal, then

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
gnome-terminal -e "vim chart.csv"
# Or xterm -e vim chart.csv &

inotifywait --quiet --recursive --monitor --event modify chart.csv | while read; do
    notify-send "hi, world"
done
```

*Update*

If you want kill the process when `vim` quits, try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

urxvt -e bash -c "vim chart.csv; kill $$"

inotifywait --quiet --recursive --monitor --event modify chart.csv | while read; do
    notify-send "hi, world"
done
```

Comment: Ok! I would like to run it into the same shell, since first I go to the folder to execute the script. Is it possible to achieve this? I get the following error: `stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Comment: Yes, when I close it. At the first I can read "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal", and when I close it appears the "stty" error.

Comment: For the first message I could solve with this flag: "vim --not-a-term". However the "stty" error is more important since its frozen and I have to close the shell. (I'm actually into tmux using URxvt, so I just close the tmux window).

Comment: I also have this in my `.zshrc`: `stty intr ^j`

Comment: Did you run my script as is ? Or you made changes ?

Comment: I'm using tmux so I would like to run into it. If not, I would use `urxvt -e`, which is similar to `gnome-terminal -e`.

Comment: With tmux, are you working on a remote machine ?

Comment: In local machine only.

Comment: What do you think about using this? `< /dev/tty vim --not-a-term chart.csv &`.

Comment: Have you tries that ?  It should work.

Comment: Yes. It works fine, but when I close the file, I have to cancel the process with Ctrl+c. It says: "Watches established." in the last line.

Comment: Your `inotifywait ... | while read ...` is independent of `vim`, It's normal you need to quit with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Close the process when that file is closed, would be possible? I tried with two inotifywait without luck. Something like this: `inotifywait -e close_write adsense.csv | while read; do`

Comment: Nice one! Now I'm doing this with tmux: `tmux new-window bash -c "vim chart.csv; kill $$`. When I close the file, it also closes the tmux window, which is good because it returns me to the same place. Perfect!